# C++ Builder XE7 [ilink32 Error] Fatal: Unable to open file .OBJ

Tags: windows, c++builder

I got an old app and I should just change the MySQL connection but I can't build it because it wrote on C++ Builder 6.
I've got the C++ Builder XE7 and installed missed libraries then linked those path in project options but the IDE write this error:

```
[ilink32 Error] Fatal: Unable to open file '.OBJ'
```

When I remove a path of library I don't get that error then I set back this path and remove another I get again that. I'm very confused.

The full log is:

> Checking project dependencies...
>   Compiling guba2.cbproj (Debug, Win32)
>   ilink32 command line
>     c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\15.0\bin\ilink32.exe -G8 -LDebug_Build;"C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickReport\QR6-RAD-XE7\win32\release";
>     "C:\Program Files (x86)\Devart\MyDAC for RAD Studio XE7\Lib\Win32";"c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\15.0\lib\win32\release";
>     "C:\Users\Én\Downloads\Indy10C21\Win32\C21";"c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\15.0\lib\debug";cxmlfile;"c:\program files 
>     (x86)\embarcadero\studio\15.0\Projects\Lib";xmlparser;"c:\Program Files\Borland\CBuilder6\Projects";"c:\program files 
>     (x86)\embarcadero\studio\15.0\lib\obj";"c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\15.0\lib";"c:\Program Files\Borland\CBuilder6\MyDac\Lib";
>     "c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\15.0\lib\psdk";cxmlfile;"c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\15.0\Projects\Lib";xmlparser;
>     "c:\Program Files\Borland\CBuilder6\Projects";"c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\15.0\lib\obj";"c:\program files 
>     (x86)\embarcadero\studio\15.0\lib";"c:\Program Files\Borland\CBuilder6\MyDac\Lib";"c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\15.0\lib\psdk";
>     "C:\Program Files (x86)\Devart\MyDAC for RAD Studio XE7\Lib\Win32";"c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\15.0\lib\win32\release";"c:\program 
>     files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\15.0\lib\win32\release\psdk";"C:\Program Files (x86)\FastReports\LibD21";"C:\Program Files 
>     (x86)\Raize\CS5\Lib\RS-XE7\Win32";"C:\Program Files (x86)\Devart\MyDAC for RAD Studio XE7\Lib\Win32";"C:\Program Files 
>     (x86)\QuickReport\QR6-RAD-XE7\win32\release";"C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickReport\QR6-RAD-XE7\win32\debug";
>     C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\15.0\DCP -jDebug_Build;"C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickReport\QR6-RAD-XE7\win32\release";"C:\Program Files 
>     (x86)\Devart\MyDAC for RAD Studio XE7\Lib\Win32";"c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\15.0\lib\win32\release";
>     "C:\Users\Én\Downloads\Indy10C21\Win32\C21";"c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\15.0\lib\debug";cxmlfile;"c:\program files 
>     (x86)\embarcadero\studio\15.0\Projects\Lib";xmlparser;"c:\Program Files\Borland\CBuilder6\Projects";"c:\program files 
>     (x86)\embarcadero\studio\15.0\lib\obj";"c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\15.0\lib";"c:\Program Files\Borland\CBuilder6\MyDac\Lib";
>     "c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\15.0\lib\psdk";cxmlfile;"c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\15.0\Projects\Lib";xmlparser;
>     "c:\Program Files\Borland\CBuilder6\Projects";"c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\15.0\lib\obj";"c:\program files 
>     (x86)\embarcadero\studio\15.0\lib";"c:\Program Files\Borland\CBuilder6\MyDac\Lib";"c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\15.0\lib\psdk";
>     "C:\Program Files (x86)\Devart\MyDAC for RAD Studio XE7\Lib\Win32";"c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\15.0\lib\win32\release";"c:\program 
>     files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\15.0\lib\win32\release\psdk";"C:\Program Files (x86)\FastReports\LibD21";"C:\Program Files 
>     (x86)\Raize\CS5\Lib\RS-XE7\Win32";"C:\Program Files (x86)\Devart\MyDAC for RAD Studio XE7\Lib\Win32";"C:\Program Files 
>     (x86)\QuickReport\QR6-RAD-XE7\win32\release";"C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickReport\QR6-RAD-XE7\win32\debug";
>     C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\15.0\DCP -l. -v -Gn 
>     -GA"C:\Users\N7409~1\AppData\Local\Temp\vfs15D2.tmp"="C:\Users\Én\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\Projects\makosguba kiszallitas 2\Unit1.dfm" -aa -V5.0 
>     -Tpe  c0w32 memmgr.lib sysinit.obj Debug_Build\guba2.obj Debug_Build\kaja_classes.obj Debug_Build\md5.obj Debug_Build\online_orders.obj 
>     Debug_Build\order_classes.obj Debug_Build\Unit1.obj Debug_Build\user_classes.obj , .\guba2.exe , .\guba2.map , vcl.lib rtl.lib vclx.lib bdertl.lib 
>     dbrtl.lib dac60.lib mydac60.lib vcldb.lib indycore.lib indysystem.lib bcbsmp.lib IndyProtocols.lib dac210.lib mydac210.lib vclimg.lib xmlrtl.lib 
>     vclactnband.lib QRWRunDXE7w64.lib import32.lib cp32mt.lib , , guba2.res 
>   [ilink32 Error] Fatal: Unable to open file '.OBJ'
>   Failed
>   Elapsed time: 00:00:11.8

Comment: It's hard to tell from that output, where does the command end and where the its output starts. Might be because of `cp32mt.lib , , guba2.res` (nothing between the *comma*s)?

Comment: Thanks for your response.
What can it be between the commas? I do not understand settings of this compiler, very differ from linux style solutions for me.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the instruction `#pragma link "XXX.Obj"`.